# How to remove one class after it has been toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm trying to figure out how to make my navbar open again, without refreshing the page, after it has already been opened and automatically closed. The original state of the ul tag is .bubbles, when clicked for the first the the class bubbles-active is toggled, and when one of the links is clicked bubbles-passive is toggled, but not removed- meaning my ul tag has both classes toggled (bubbles-passive and bubbles-active).

I reckon thats the bug, but I'm failing at figuring out how to make the code work. Should I make the bubbles-passive class remove itself after it's been called, and if so, how do I make that happen?

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar" id="navbar"> 
            <ul class="bubbles">
                <li>
                    <a href="#myoffers" id="offers-link" class="offersp" > 01. My offers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#work" id="work-link" class="workp"> 02. My work</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="./schedule.html" id="contact-link" > 03. Contact me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="./hire.html" id="hire-link"> 04. Hire me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.bubbles{
    display: block;
    z-index: 5;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #a239ca, #4717f6);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 35px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.bubbles-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.bubbles-passive{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

@keyframes bubblesFade{
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.bubbles li{
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #e7dfdd;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.burger{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle .line{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}

.toggle .line1{
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line2{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}

.reset .line{
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px);
}

.reset .line1{
    opacity: 1;
}

.reset .line2{
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

JavaScript

```
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.bubbles');
  const bubbles = document.querySelectorAll('.bubbles li');
  const offers = document.querySelector('.offersp');
    const work = document.querySelector('.workp');

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('bubbles-active');

    bubbles.forEach((link, index) => {
      if(link.style.animation){
        link.style.animation = ''
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `bubblesFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
      console.log(index / 7);
      }
    });

    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });

  offers.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('bubbles-passive');

    burger.classList.toggle('reset');
});

work.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('bubbles-passive');

    burger.classList.toggle('reset');
});

}

navSlide();
```

Here's a codepen of the problem https://codepen.io/jelaaxo/pen/JjGQMPM

Comment: You need to create a snippet reproducing your exact issue.

Comment: Hey, I edited the code I posted, not sure if the code snippet reproduces the bug automatically or not?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to be able to debug? It will greatly increase this question's chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Here's a codepen of the problem https://codepen.io/jelaaxo/pen/JjGQMPM

Comment: It works correctly in your codepen

Comment: Maybe I didn't correctly explain the problem, when I click on the burger menu, the nav opens. But when I click on one of the links, my offers for example, the nav closes automatically but it won't open again (by clicking the burger) without refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have few suggestion. Use *id* for selecting to elements instead of classes.
You can use for id for *ul*.

```
<ul id="navUl" class="bubbles">
```

Then select is using this.

```
const nav = document.getElementById(navUl);
```

Then you have to check *bubbles-active* is exist in class list.

```
    if (nav.classList.contains("bubbles-active")) {
      nav.classList.remove("bubbles-active");
      nav.classList.add("bubbles-passive");
    } else {
      nav.classList.add("bubbles-active");
    }
```

I hope this will help you to solve your problem.